# Is the click code I wrote using POST or GET?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, click

I want to use this POST method to jump to another page to display the data is written like this?Thank you!

```
$(function () {
  $("#btnQueryString").bind("click", function () {
    var url = "BPT.html?marquecl=" + encodeURIComponent($(".MarqueCl").val()) + 
      "&serie=" + encodeURIComponent($(".Serie").val()) +
      "&category=" + encodeURIComponent($(".Category").val()) + 
      "&kyword=" + encodeURIComponent($("#kword").val());
    window.location.href = url;
  });
});
```

Comment: That's making a GET request. To make a POST you will either need to submit a `<form method="post">` element, or make an AJAX requuest

Comment: How do you write with POST?

Answer (score 0):

This code making GET Request, for POST you can use AJAX request or from FORM (with specification Method type as POST)